# Can i Use the DE as in 13.04 on 12.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade

i want to use 13.04 Desktop Environment(DE) in 12.04 is it possible without upgrade.i am using 32 bit ubuntu.
Please tell me if this is possible or not.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Hi TSDCR, you will need to be more specific. What is it from the 13.04 DE that you want to use in 12.04? The DE is in principle the same

Comment: Hi Jacob, i would like to use the appearance and icon package used in 13.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [Y PPA Manager](https://launchpad.net/y-ppa-manager) and search for "unity"[image]